# Opencart OCMod how to apply modifications to all .php files in all directories

Tags: php, xml, opencart2.x, ocmod

When I need to apply modifications to one file, I use the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Modification name</name>
    <file path="system/library/cart/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<some code to apply>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[// <some code to apply>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
<modification>
```

Target file is set via `path` attribute of `file` tag.

How to apply modifications to all .php files? I've tried with no luck the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Modification name</name>
    <file path="**/*.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<some code to apply>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[// <some code to apply>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
<modification>
```

Comment: Your xml is not valid. your first CDATA block is not closed correctly. a `]` is missing. but not sure if that is your question here.

Comment: You're right, code snippet is not full. I'll modify the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System

> Please note that all file paths must start with either admin, catalog or system

Maybe give this a try

```
<file path="system/*/*/*.php">
```

where `/*/*/` is the path to where all the php files that you wish to include

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's the defenetly the step into right direction. But unfortunatelly it doesn't work. I've tried `<file path="admin/**/*.php">` - no luck, but, for ex., `<file path="admin/controller/sale/*.php">` works fine

Comment: `<file path="admin/**/*.php">` does not work!... `<file path="admin/*/*/*.php">` should.

Answer (score 0):

To apply for all themes (directory) and one file example:

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/extension/payment/cod.twig>
```

To apply for all themes (directory) and several files example:

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/extension/payment/{cod,bank_transfer,cheque}.twig>
```

I do not think that you need to apply for all files the same things in OCMOD

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've already seen examples of approach you provided in thirdparty extensions. It's usefull for templates modifications. But I'm interested in applying modifications to all php files.  I have a  theoretical interest, because I've already found the solution for my problem without modifying all files.